# Spring Boot - How to define log file location in external config file (or programmatically)?

Tags: file, spring-boot, logging, configuration, configuration-files

I have a config file `application.yml` for my Spring Boot webservice. Also I have a line `logging.file=/path/to/spring-app.log` in my `application.properties`.

The user won't be able to access `application.properties`, but only the yaml config, nonetheless should be able to define the location for logfiles. I'd like to configure logging either from code or insert value from yaml into properties.

How can I either
a) use a value from `application.yml` to define `logging.file`?
b) set the log file location programmatically?

Comment: Why do you have yml and properties file?

Comment: requirement – user must be able to configure some things via yml (but other things must only be configured by devs)

Comment: And where do you put the yml file? If it's where the jar file is it will override the values in your application.properties

Comment: no, but they also don't define same values. i.e. user in can configure output location for created file in yml (an should be able to configure log file location there), server port can be configured by dev in properties.

Answer (score 0):

Argh easy-peasy:
Just put

`logging:
    file: /path/to/log.log`

(stupid me forgot to put the colons)